# Lottie nuget, throws "java exited with code 1" error in Android (Xamarin forms)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, nuget, lottie

I have installed Com.Airbnb.Xamarin.Forms.Lottie nuget version 4.0.8. When I have run the app in Android device it throws java exited with code 1 error at compile time.

In my project Xamarin.Forms nuget version is 4.8.0.1821

Pro guard is disabled in my Android build option and Multidex option is also enabled. Also I have tried to increase heap size but it still not works, does anyone know how to fix this or any workaround?[image]

Build Output:[image]

Comment: Did you check your Build Output?

Comment: It's not getting build, I have added screen shot of output please check.

Comment: That's a screenshot of the build errors. You have the click on Build Output to show the output.

Comment: Ensure your project targets androidX also try to install an older version of the nuget, this all can just come from lottie, it is a nuget currently full of issues (unfortunately).

Comment: I have tried different older versions of lottie but none of them are working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the real reason of this error. This error is actually cause by the modernhttpclient (2.4.2). I have removed this nuget from all projects and the error is gone! So, the real culprit is modernhttpclient and not Lottie.

I hope this might be helpful to someone.